# Google Apps Marketplace Listing Review Request

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-apps-marketplace, marketplace, chrome-web-store

We are publishing our app for the first time in Google market place and our app is meeting OAuth 2.0 requirement from Google.As a part of publishing our app into google market place we need to submit Google Apps Marketplace Listing Review Request. On this request there is a question that ask for Chrome Web Store Item ID for our application. I do not know how to find that ID and include that on the request. Can any one share his/her thoughts?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Once you upload your app in the webstore, open the [Chrome Webstore developer dashboard](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard).

Find the App you need to get the ID and click the edit button next to the App. Once edit view is open, you can get the required ID from the url.

Posting the screenshot of the Chrome Webstore developer dashboard below:

[image]

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your update. Are you saying we need to register our app also in the webstore developer dashboard? Why should we do that ? We have register our into google dev dashboard in market place already and I thought it was sufficient. Thanks

Comment: Please check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/listing) for more details on steps to publish your app for first time for more clarification.